# Mod_rewrite Subdomain Folder to Root Domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a folder on my Subdomain:

```
sub.domain.com/folder
```

to my main domain

```
domain.com/folder
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com/folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain\.com/folder/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```